# call to non-static method from a static method crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static, crash

I am trying to call to non-static method from a static method but the app crash and I don't know why this is happened. I would be happy if you can help me understood why this is happened and how I can fix it.

Static function -

```
    public static void myPlace(String place, String titles) {

    if (place == "[]") {
        // Not found Skip
    } else {
        Log.d("placea - ", place);
        Log.d("titles - ", titles);

        BackgroundProcess b = new BackgroundProcess();
        b.addNotification();

    }
```

Non Static function -

```
    public void addNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
                    .setContentText("This is a test notification");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyNotification.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(FM_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Log -

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                              Process: alon.myplace, PID: 18679
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
                                                                  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
                                                                  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4160)
                                                                  at alon.myplace.BackgroundProcess.addNotification(BackgroundProcess.java:238)
                                                                  at alon.myplace.BackgroundProcess.myPlace(BackgroundProcess.java:224)
                                                                  at alon.myplace.PlacesDisplayTask.doInBackground(PlacesDisplayTask.java:33)
                                                                  at alon.myplace.PlacesDisplayTask.doInBackground(PlacesDisplayTask.java:13)
                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `if (place == "[]") {`??? Use `equals(...)` for Strings please.

Comment: e.g., `if ("[]".equals(place) {`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks but this is not my problem

Comment: Maybe not now, but it **will** be your problem once you fix your current issue! Also, what "error" are you seeing?

Comment: Please post the crash logs.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I add the crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the context which you are passing  in

`Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyNotification.class);`

`this` is null.

Please check how you are getting the context. It should be a valid context and should not be null.

Comment: Thanks but I not sure what is the way to achieve that, how can I getting the right context ?

Comment: Where is `addNotification()` method ?

Comment: The addNotification() is in the same class with myPlace function. The classes in a background class called BackgroundProcess.

Comment: You need to pass the context all the way from activity/fragment to this class and then use it.

Comment: Wow, it looks like that this method is not so efficient but thanks anyway for the help !